# .htaccess mapping subdomain to a directory having codeigniter framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I know there is millions of solution is available for redirect subdomain to directory. But still I am facing the problem.

I want to map subdomain in the following manner

1. demo1.example.com to demo1 dir
2. demo2.example.com to demo2 dir

I am using the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo1\.example\.com$
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo1/
    RewriteRule (.*) /demo1/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo2\.example\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo2/
    RewriteRule (.*) /demo2/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is working fine **but  i am getting the dir name in url** like demo1.example.com/demo1/
for this i have used the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^demo1/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

but unable to remove demo1 from url 
i have codeigniter framework in demo1 dir having following htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: `#Redirect to www location with subdirectory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/directory/index.html [R=301,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complete installation of the framework in each subdirectory and you're not doing any kind of dynamic mapping, then rewriting URLs isn't the best solution.

Just create a virtual host for each installation and set the server name accordingly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/demo1
  ServerName demo1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/demo2
  ServerName demo2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Depending on what kind of hosting you're using, you can create virtual hosts in your hosting management backend, or check the [Apache 2.2 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for more information.